# Alter add_meta_box

Tags: plugins, metabox

I am trying to create a custom post type (through a plugin).
The post type must be pretty similar to a page, so I would like to load meta boxes from other plugins and theme in my custom post type.

I registered my post type like this :

```
register_post_type('product', array(        
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "Product", 
    "menu_icon" => 'dashicons-media-text',
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail','revisions' )
));
```

How load metadbox plugin loaded like this :

```
add_meta_box("page-meta", "settings", "pageMeta", "page", "normal", "low");
```

Is there a way to inherit of page metaboxes ?

Comment: I don't know what the question means. Are you trying to ask if there a way to load metaboxes intended for another post type?

Comment: Yes, it is. I would like to load metabox from type "page" to my custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can try but it just won't be any kind of reliable. There was a similar question while back — [get registered metaboxes by post type or post ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/191933/847)

Overall it is somewhat possible to fetch metaboxes like that, **but** it was never designed to work like that. **Also** it's common for related code to check for post type (to not mess up unrelated ones) so it won't work properly, even if meta box shows us.